# Oracle 10: pivot and unpivot without using pivot and unpivot

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle 10 so I can't use PIVOT and UNPIVOT.  My problem is the following.  Please suppose you have this Oracle table:

[image]

I would like to write an Oracle query that, without using PIVOT / UNPIVOT, produces the following output:

[image]

In the source table, you can see that I have two main blocks of data: date related to February 2015, and date related to March 2015.

The (KEY1, KEY2) = (11111, A) is present for February 2015, and absent for March 2015.

The (KEY1, KEY2) = (55555, E) is absent for February 2015, and present for March 2015.

Please help me to write the query in order to produce the desired output.

Thank you very much for considering my request.

EDIT #01: Please suppose that in the table are present only two big blocks with two different dates.  For example, 1,000,037 records with 01/02/2015, and 999,967 records with 01/03/2015 (it's only an example).

EDIT #02: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi

Comment: Is there or could have more than that two dates ? Or it is just then two ?

Comment: EDIT: Please suppose that in the table are present only two big blocks with two different dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below one will work.

```
  SELECT key1,
         key2,
         MAX ("01/02/2015") AS "01/02/2015",
         MAX ("01/03/2015") AS "01/03/2015"
    FROM (SELECT a.KEY1,
                 a.KEY2,
                 CASE
                    WHEN A.DATE1 = TO_DATE ('01/02/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                    THEN
                       a.VALUE
                 END
                    AS "01/02/2015",
                 CASE
                    WHEN a.DATE1 = TO_DATE ('01/03/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                    THEN
                       a.VALUE
                 END
                    AS "01/03/2015"
            FROM TABLE2 a)
GROUP BY key1, key2
ORDER BY key1;
```

**Edit**

Instead of writing nested select u can do it in a single query also

```
  SELECT a.KEY1,
         a.KEY2,
         MAX (
            CASE
               WHEN A.DATE1 = TO_DATE ('01/02/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN a.VALUE
            END)
            AS "01/02/2015",
         MAX (
            CASE
               WHEN a.DATE1 = TO_DATE ('01/03/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN a.VALUE
            END)
            AS "01/03/2015"
    FROM TABLE2 a
GROUP BY key1, key2
ORDER BY key1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help.  Any other edit will be appreciated.  Keep in mind that TABLE2 has about 10 million records for the first date, and 10 million records for the second date.

Comment: @UltraCommit it will be better if u partition the table for effective performance and also if we have index.

Comment: The table is already partitioned by DATE1 ;-)   And I query only two partition dates ;-)